# regular expression to replace an xml attribute

Tags: regex

I have an xml file of the form:

```
<property name="foo" value="this is a long value">stuff</property>
```

There are many properties but I want to match the one with name foo and then replace its value attribute with something else as so:

```
<property name="foo" value="yet another long value">stuff</property>
```

I was thinking to write a regular expression to match everything after "foo" to the end of the tag ( ">" ) and replace that, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I'm trying to do this using sed, if that's any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/property name=\"foo\" value=\"([^\"]*)\"/`

Then just replace the first submatch with the new value of your wishing.

Comment: Hi Tommi, Thanks for the helpful post. If I read your correctly, only the first word of the value attribute is matched, yes? What if it contains many words? (I've revised the original post to highlight what I mean).

Comment: From what I can read of this regex, the group n#1 will contain all the words inside the double-quoted value attribute.

Comment: Yep, it contains everything between the double quotes. Basically the part \"([^\"]*)\" translates to "something that starts with a double-quote, has any number of non-double-quote characters in it and ends in a double-quote, saving the stuff in between the double quotes in a submatch.

A really really really cool tool for testing out regexps is RegEx Coach:
http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

Three thumbs up for that one!

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you! I misread the syntax earlier and I was having some setting up the search/replace but everything is sorted now. RegEx Coach also looks like a great little tool; I think they have an older version for Linux/Mac too. yay!

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't want to use a regex for manipulating an xml file.  Please instead consider [xslt](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), which is aware of xml rules and won't cause your transformed document to become malformed.

Comment: While I agree with this in general, I'm not using this code to process transactions. Rather I just want to modify a build configuration file that will let me change the contents of an about box. I'd like to do it all as part of a bash script and writing an XSL is overkill.

Comment: @Daniel: If you specify your needs some more, you may find that an XSL transformation to change one attribute is a lot less difficult than you might think.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's not about the difficulty; I'm coding against a static build script target which is seldom changing. To use XSL I'd have to write a stylesheet and some other code to actually do the transformation (I don't think bash has tools for working with xml). I feel it's all a bit much just to change the build number in an about box.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in the context of a browser, you could create a throwaway DOM node containing the XML and just walk that to replace attribute values.

This function will call a callback on every child node:

```
const walkDOM = (node, callback) => {
  callback(node);
  [...node.children].forEach(child => {
    walkDOM(child, callback)
  });
}
```

You can then use this to update any attributes matching conditions you'd like (here replacing any, assuming you have an XML string called `svgXml`:

```
  const containerEl = document.createElement('div');
  containerEl.innerHTML = svgXml;

  walkDOM(containerEl, el => {
    const attributes = [...el.attributes];
    attributes.forEach(attr => {
      if (attr.name === 'foo' && attr.value === 'this is a long value']) {
        attr.value = 'yet another long value';
      }
    });
  });

  const outputSvgXml = containerEl.innerHTML;
```

Of course you could further optimize this by using querySelectorAll(`property`) to only walk `<property>` nodes, etc.

I found this useful for updating an SVG while taking advantage of the browser's robustness.