# How to replace value of xml attributes matching a regex in bash?

Tags: xml, regex, replace, sed, awk

I would like to substitute the values of XML attributes matching a regex in a file in bash.

```
 <Resource name="MailSession" auth="Container" type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.smtp.host="localhost" mail.smtp.user="foo" mail.smtp.passwd="12345678"
            mail.pop3.host="localhost" mail.pop3.user="foo" mail.pop3.passwd="12345678"/>
```

should be transformed to

```
 <Resource name="MailSession" auth="Container" type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.smtp.host="***" mail.smtp.user="foo" mail.smtp.passwd="***"
            mail.pop3.host="***" mail.pop3.user="foo" mail.pop3.passwd="***"/>
```

This should be possible using sed or awk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression to replace an xml attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780445/regular-expression-to-replace-an-xml-attribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have my sed command like this:

```
sed -E 's@(mail[.][^.]+[.])(host|passwd)="[^"]*"@\1\2="***"@g' file
```

Output:

```
 <Resource name="MailSession" auth="Container" type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.smtp.host="***" mail.smtp.user="foo" mail.smtp.passwd="***"
            mail.pop3.host="***" mail.pop3.user="foo" mail.pop3.passwd="***"/>
```

You can add `-i` option to sed to directly modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML file is called "test.xml" you can:

```
cat test.xml | sed 's/host="[^"]*/host="***/g' | sed 's/passwd="[^"]*/passwd="***/g'
```

If you are reading the file from other place (such as HTTP connection, or whatever) you can modify the first command of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
 awk -F\" '/host/ {$2=$6="***"}1' OFS=\" file
<Resource name="MailSession" auth="Container" type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.smtp.host="***" mail.smtp.user="foo" mail.smtp.passwd="***"
            mail.pop3.host="***" mail.pop3.user="foo" mail.pop3.passwd="***"/>
```