# Find and Replace value using Regular Expressions in Sed

Tags: replace, sed

I need to search and replace the value for CustomerEMailID in xml file with the sed search and replace sed s/// . I was able to get the value for CustomerEMailID, how do I replace it with emailID using sed?

```
//Print the value
sed -n 's/.*CustomerEMailID="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' xmltoconvert.xml


//xml file:
<Order
    CustomerEMailID="XXXX"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression to replace an xml attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780445/regular-expression-to-replace-an-xml-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(.*CustomerEMailID="\)[^"]*\(.*\)/\1emailID\2/' xmltoconvert.xml
```

It will replace the value you want and print the whole file to terminal.

Input file:

```
<Order
    CustomerEMailID="XXXX">
```

Output file:

```
<Order
    CustomerEMailID="emailID">
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! Exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you could use the following:

```
awk -v email="emailID" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /CustomerEMailID=/) $(i+1)=email}1' file
```

It first sets the field separators `FS` and `OFS` to `"`.

Then it will look for the index of parameter matching the pattern `/CustomerEMailID=/` and replace the next parameter to the string stored in the `awk` variable `email`.

Comment: Thanks Oliv! I was looking for a sed based find and replace but this helps too.